# Set Session value from JavaScript and Get Session value in C#

Tags: session, viewstate

Is it available to set the value from javascript(Session / ViewState)  and get the value in C#  without using hidden field??

---

Its work to store the value from javascript , and available to get the value in C# (page.request["Token"]) , but its not working for me because there have a postback action " form.submit();"

```
 function setToken(Token) {
    try {
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        var field = document.createElement("input");
        field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        field.setAttribute("name", 'Token');
        field.setAttribute("value", accessToken);
        form.appendChild(field);
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    } catch (err) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit a value from your clientside code to your serverside code, you'll need to submit it in some kind of request. A form post would be one way, but if you don't want the page to reload it could equally well be an AJAX request:

```
function setToken(accessToken) {
   $.post('/SetToken', { Token: accessToken });
}
```

Using jQuery there as it'll save you a lot of the trouble involved in getting AJAX to work the same way across browsers.

In the example I'm posting a request to a page called `/SetToken`, which could be any url in your website where you have code that can update the token. Your own example submits a form without an `action`, which means it'll submit to the current page. You could easily do that as well

```
$.post(location.href, { Token: accessToken });
```